# Exist some way to express addeventlistener and getelementbyId in Angular7?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I was wondering if exist some kind of method or whatever, to express the method of addEventListener and getElementById in typescript to use it

I don't know if using decorator  host will help me, I am not tried that yet but I think that could be a possible way to solve this.

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active')
);

signInButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active')
);
```

I just want to set this in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

You put a click handler on the buttons and use ngClass to add the class to the container.

```
<button (click)="signUp()">Sign up</button>

<button (click)="signIn()">Sign in</button>

<div id="container" [ngClass]="{ 'right-panel-active': showPanel }"></div>
```

and in the TypeScript

```
showPanel = false;

signUp() {
  this.showPanel = true;
}

signIn() {
  this.showPanel = false;
}
```

Comment: Here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7bkdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html